# Latitude and longitude cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies, geolocation

Good afternoon,

I'm trying to save in a 2 different cookies the information of latitude and longitude. This code worked on my computer, but it's not working on my mobile devices (the cookies are empty). What can I do in order to make it work?

That's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getGPS()
{
    if (navigator.geolocation)
    {  
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showGPS);
    }
    else
    {  
        gpsText.innerText = "No GPS Functionality.";  
    }
}
function showGPS(position)
{
    document.cookie="latitude="+position.coords.latitude;
    document.cookie="longitude="+position.coords.longitude;
}
</script>
```

**Edit:** My website is : http://www.idermo.es/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=123&Itemid=747

Is that well geolocalised for you?

**Edit:**

And that's my body tag:

```
<body onLoad="getGPS();">
```

Why is my code not entering the Javascript creation cookie? Because I have tested with a "alert("wow")" and it didn't show anything.

Thanks,

Regards,

Comment: which mobile browser doesn't support cookies? :/

Comment: What device is not working? Is the callback actually fired? Do you actually need the value in a cookie? Try localstorage instead if you do not need the data on the server.

Comment: Hello.
I'm trying with iPhone 4S - Safari and my cookie is always empty.

Yes, I need latitude and longitude on a value because HTML 5 gelocation is the only system I know regarding the exact latitude and longitude from a 3G mobile device. And I need a cookie because after that I create the map with PHP.

Do you know why this is not working? Because when this worked, it will be everything done :)

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check if code run showGPS function ?

what about

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getGPS()
{
    if (navigator.geolocation)
    {  
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showGPS);
    }
    else
    {  
        gpsText.innerText = "No GPS Functionality.";  
    }
}
function showGPS(position)
{
    alert('Wow!');
    document.cookie="latitude="+position.coords.latitude;
    document.cookie="longitude="+position.coords.longitude;
}
</script>
```

?

P.S> I have no iPhone , but my android browser has secure setting which allow/deny use cookies and navigator

Comment: Good idea Vasil. It didn't show the "Wow" alert. I'm going to edit my first thread and put there my "body html tag". Thanks, Regards.

Comment: Thanks Vasil, you gave me the idea of delete the "OnLoad" tag in my body html, and then it worked! The cookies are created and now it's working correct :). Thanks!!